# Can we change this user's name?

Tags: discussion, new-users

https://askubuntu.com/users/593258/rabies

Can we change this users name? This looks silly

Comment: The correct way to deal with this is usually to flag one of the user's posts for moderator attention and explain the situation. As it is, I don't think that's particularly offensive.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. @ArtOfCode

Comment: Why is rabies offensive? I don't see why someone would be offended by that, it is just silly.

Comment: LOLZ. i'l go edit this post now

Answer (score 12):

If their username contained profanity or explicit content (yes, this has happened before with other users) then indeed it should be flagged. But the name of a viral disease?

Should we ban "flu" then?

Comment: Sorry :P @nathanosman

Answer (score 7):

Even if the name were something silly, like Bob The Builder, we would still have no right as mods to go and change it or even to ask the person to the change it. So long as it is nothing offensive or profane, we really have no reason to bother anyone over a name.